# Any changes/improvement for LINQ 2010 vs LINQ 2008

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm VB.NET user and now learning LINQ. The book I'm reading now focus on LINQ 2008 VB.NET. I want to know whether there are changes/improvement in LINQ 2010?

p/s: I'm reading this book: Pro LINQ Language Integrated Query in VB 2008

Answer (score 1):

It appears that most of the improvements between linq in .NET 3.5 and linq in .NET 4.0 have to do with improved capabilities in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace.

http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/08/10/expression-trees-take-two-introducing-system-linq-expressions-v4-0.aspx

VB.NET 2010 adds support for multiline lambda statements. 
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-vb-2010-enhancements/